# Can't specify a canvas created through Javascript as a drop area

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have created two canvases in a div using Javascript. I have another div with an image. I want to drop that image into the canvas. But I am getting error in adding events to the canvases. I am trying to set the events "ondragover" and "ondrop". But I am getting the error that event is not defined.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function dragIt(theEvent) {
theEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", theEvent.target.id);   
}

function dropIt(theEvent) {
var theData = theEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
dt = document.getElementById(theData);
theEvent.preventDefault();  
}    

window.onload = function() {     
  var c2 = document.createElement('canvas');
  c2.width = 140;
  c2.height = 140;
  c2.style.cssText = 'position:relative;top:70px;left:498px;border:2px  solid black;';
  var ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d');    
  document.body.appendChild(c2);
  c2.ondragover=event.preventDefault();
  c2.ondrop=dropIt(event);


  var c3 = document.createElement('canvas');
  c3.width = 140;
  c3.height = 140;
  c3.style.cssText = 'position:relative;top:70px;left:502px; border:2px  solid black;';
  var ctx3 = c3.getContext('2d');
  document.body.appendChild(c3);     

  };  
</script>

</head>
    <body>
    <div class="pics">
    <div id="place1">
    <img src="images/211.jpg" width="80" height="80" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event);" id="pic1" />
    </div>   
    <div style = "position:absolute;top:150px;width:300;height:400;left:500px; border:2px  solid black;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c2.ondragover=event.preventDefault();
c2.ondrop=dropIt(event);
```

These lines will execute some functions, and assign the result of that as an event listener. That's not what you want, you need to assign the function object itself. Also, the execution will fail because there is no `event` object that time - it will be created somewhen in the future, when the drag really happens, and be passed to the function as an argument.

```
c2.ondragover = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
};
c2.ondrop = dropIt;
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working but when function dropIt is called, the line theEvent.preventDefault(); is not working properly and browser opens the image. Is there any issue in that!!

Comment: I don't think so, but maybe somewhere before that line in dropIt? Are there any exceptions thrown, e.g. when there is no element with the dragged id?

Comment: I got it fixed! Now i want to draw the image into the canvas it is dropped in. So, how can i do that in dropIt function? That image is drawn into the canvas in which the image is dropped!

Comment: Hm, I don't know much about drag&drop-events or the data they carry. I think that would be another question...